# Add fadeIn to Jquery load content into DIV

Tags: jquery, load, fadein

I have this code:

```
$('.LINK').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

$('#Grid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .project_thumb');
});
```

Which works perfectly. All I want to do is say 'load .project_thumb with a fade in' - I have tried

```
$('#Grid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .project_thumb');
$(.project_thumb).fadeIn();
```

And

```
$('#Grid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .project_thumb');
$(this).fadeIn();
```

And

```
$('#Grid').fadeIn().load($(this).attr('href') + ' .project_thumb');
```

But none of this works. Please note I'm trying to target the content (.project_thumb) and not the #Grid container. Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would make both you and ours life easier ? :)

Comment: you can add a callback to `.load()` http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/6A6wq/

Comment: thanks, since I'm loading content (.project_thumb) into the #Grid I've added it like this, but doesn't seem to work    $('.LINK').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    $('#Grid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .project_thumb'), function() {
$(this).fadeIn();
});

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do it like this.

```
$('.LINK').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var html = $.load($(this).attr('href'));

    $('#Grid').html(html).fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I'm trying to load .project_thumb into #Grid, not the whole html doc. And I want to fade in the .project_thumb, not the #Grid

Comment: can you please show what result you are getting from the url?

Comment: The syntax you are using is wrong. You cant add a class in load function as it only gets a url and a callback function. So You have this option. `$('project_thumb').load($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(5000);`

Comment: I've applied your code to : $('.LINK').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
$('.project_thumb').load($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(5000);

}); But this throws a 404 Page not found. The original syntax works, I just don't know how to add a fade to that.  Anyway, I'm trying to load .project_thumb into Grid, the code you posted doesn't mention Grid.

Comment: Then use my original code in the answer and add this line `$('#Grid').hide();` after the `event.preventDefault();` line. Actually `fadeIn()` function work on elements which display is set to none. As `fadeIn()` changes display to block but with animation.

Comment: .project_thumb needs to be loaded into #Grid. If #Grid is hidden, then .project_thumb won't be visible.

Comment: It will be because the fadeIn will display it with animation. fadeIn will not work if #Grid is already visible it wont be effected. But if its hidden then fadeIn will display it with animation.